# Operator used tempdb to spill data . The estimated row are less than real rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a query that takes around 32 seconds, I tried many ways to fix the performance problem.

The first thing I tried is adding a new column that contain date and time as an integer. After I added this column to a non clustered index, the query now is executed in 2 seconds. but when I look at the execution plan, I see that there are some warnings.

**Edit :**

```
DECLARE @StartDate int=2010010110,--2010-01-01 10:00
        @EndDate int=2019101011 --2019-10-10 11:00

SELECT newDate, 
    IdFluide
    IdUsage,       
   SUM(c.[Conso-KW]) AS ConsoKW
FROM fait.Consommation  AS c WITH(FORCESCAN, INDEX(0)) 
where  newDate >= @StartDate 
  AND newDate <= @EndDate
  AND  IdSource = 1
  AND IdTypeFluide = 1

 AND IdUsage > 0

AND exists(select 1 from  geo.DimGeographie dg  
       INNER JOIN geo.ActivePerimeterDetail apd 
              ON dg.ContractId = apd.ContractId 
              AND dg.IdNiveau3=apd.PerimeterId 
              AND apd.PerimeterLevelId=3
              AND dg.ContractId = 2  
              AND dg.ModeGeo='PA' 
              AND apd.ContractId = 2 
              AND UserId = 8
       where c.IdGeographie = dg.IdGeographie  
     )    
GROUP BY newDate,
     IdFluide,
     IdUsage
```

The table `fait.Consommation` contain around 4.5M rows.

The table `geo.DimGeographie` contain around 20K rows.

The table `geo.ActivePerimeterDetail` contain around 43K rows.

I have clustered and non-clustered index in all tables.
[image: ![![enter image description here]
[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried to update statistics and I saw many articles talking about such problems, but trying all what they suggest, doesn't solve my problem.

```
 update statistics [fait].[Consommation] with fullscan

 update statistics [geo].[DimGeographie] with fullscan

 update statistics [geo].[ActivePerimeterDetail] with fullscan

 update statistics [fait].[Consommation] [IX_GeographicalConsumption] with fullscan

 update statistics geo.DimGeographie [IX_Test] with fullscan

 update statistics geo.ActivePerimeterDetail [UQ_ActivePerimeterDetail] with fullscan
```

When I add this code to tables in the query, I have a new execution plan and speed up the query, now the query execute in one second but still have same warning `WITH(FORCESCAN, INDEX(0))`

[XML Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkoE9SUaH)

**Indexes : Edit**

1. Table `[fait].[Consommation]`

*NONCLUSTERED INDEX :*

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GeographicalConsumption] ON [fait].[Consommation]
    (
      [IdSource] ASC,
      [IdTypeFluide] ASC,
      [IdUsage] ASC,
      [IdFluide] ASC,
      [NewDate] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE (   
              [Conso-KW],
              [Conso-M3],
              [Euros],
              [CO2],
              [Conso-EP],
              [IdGeographie]
            ) 
    WHERE ([IdUsage]>(0)) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

*CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX:*

```
 CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [IX_Consommation] ON [fait].[Consommation] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. Table `[geo].[DimGeographie]`

*NONCLUSTERED INDEX :*

```
     CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Test] ON [geo].[DimGeographie]
     (
         [ContractId] ASC,
         [ModeGeo] ASC
     )
     INCLUDE (  
                 [IdGeographie],
                 [IdNiveau3]
             ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

*CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX:*

```
  CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [IX_DimGeographie] ON [geo].[DimGeographie] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
```

3. Table `[geo].[ActivePerimeterDetail]`

*NONCLUSTERED INDEX :*

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ActivePerimeterDetail] ON [geo].[ActivePerimeterDetail]
    (
         [ContractId] ASC,
         [UserId] ASC,
         [PerimeterLevelId] ASC,
         [PerimeterId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

*UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX:*

```
  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_ActivePerimeterDetail] ON [geo].[ActivePerimeterDetail]
  (
     [ContractId] ASC,
     [UserId] ASC,
     [PerimeterLevelId] ASC,
     [PerimeterId] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, i figured out that i need to combine the two tables `[fait].[Consommation]` and `[geo].[DimGeographie]` in one table, and i added a non clustured index in this new table.

Now the query execute in less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to approximately replicate your tables & data based on your info

**DDL & DML:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consommation](IdRef bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,IdInterface int,IdSource int,
IdUsage int,newDate int,[Conso-KW] decimal(19,6),IdTypeFluide int,IdFluide int,
IdGeographie int);

-- 2540563 matching rows
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Consommation] WITH(TABLOCK) (IdUsage,IdInterface ,IdSource,newDate,[Conso-KW],IdTypeFluide,IdFluide,IdGeographie)
SELECT TOP(2540563)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
1,
2010010110 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), -- will technically be incorrect dates but still match
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
5
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;



CREATE TABLE [dbo].DimGeographie(IdGeographie int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
,ContractId int,IdNiveau3 int,
ModeGeo varchar(10));

INSERT INTO [dbo].DimGeographie(ContractId,IdNiveau3,ModeGeo)
SELECT TOP(241)
2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
'PA'
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].ActivePerimeterDetail(ActivePerimeterDetailId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
,ContractId int,PerimeterId int
,PerimeterLevelId int, UserId int)

INSERT INTO [dbo].ActivePerimeterDetail(ContractId,PerimeterId,PerimeterLevelId,UserId)
SELECT TOP(58)
2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
3,
8
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;
```

The estimation difference appears to be due to the joins between the tables. When adding option(recompile) the estiamtes got higher, from 100K to 600K. But obviously this was not enough to get the tempdb spilling to stop.

One way I was able to get almost correct estimates is by splitting the logic up in two pieces by storing the values in a temp table. This way tempdb spilling did not happen.

**My final query**

```
DECLARE @StartDate int=2010010110,--2010-01-01 10:00
        @EndDate int=2019101011 --2019-10-10 11:00
SELECT
    newDate, 
    IdFluide,
    IdUsage,       
   c.[Conso-KW],
   c.IdGeographie,
    dg.ContractId,
    dg.IdNiveau3
INTO #TEMP
FROM dbo.Consommation  AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.DimGeographie dg 
ON c.IdGeographie = dg.IdGeographie
where  newDate >= @StartDate 
  AND newDate <= @EndDate
  AND  IdSource = 1
  AND IdTypeFluide = 1
  AND IdUsage > 0
  AND dg.ContractId = 2  
  AND dg.ModeGeo='PA' 
OPTION(RECOMPILE);



SELECT newDate,
       IdFluide,
       IdUsage,
       SUM(c.[Conso-KW]) AS ConsoKW
FROM #TEMP c
WHERE exists(select 1 from dbo.ActivePerimeterDetail apd 
              WHERE c.ContractId = apd.ContractId 
              AND c.IdNiveau3=apd.PerimeterId 
              AND apd.PerimeterLevelId=3
              AND apd.ContractId = 2 
              AND UserId = 8
     )

GROUP BY newDate,
     IdFluide,
     IdUsage
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```

[The plan of the temp table insert](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ0WUniaB)

[The plan of the final query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyA1L2o6S)

Comment: I have tried your solution, it absolutely disappears the message of tempdb but the query takes about 4 to 5 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once you try to update Statistics with FullScan

Example,

```
Update STATISTICS [fait].[Consommation] IX_GeographicalConsumption WITH FULLSCAN
```

Then avoid using `inequality (<>)` in `predicate`.Use any alternative.

BTW, what can be all possible value of `IdUsage` ?

If columns of `geo.DimGeographie dg`  and `geo.ActivePerimeterDetail apd`  are not require in  resultset then use `EXISTS`.

This  guarantee to return only require number of row from join.

```
 SELECT IdFluide,
       newDate,
       IdUsage,
       SUM(c.[Conso-KW]) AS ConsoKW
FROM fait.Consommation  AS c 
where 
   IdSource = 1
  AND IdTypeFluide = 1
  AND UserId = 8
 AND IdUsage > 0-- remove <>
  AND newDate >= @StartDate 
  AND newDate <= @EndDate)
and exists(select 1 from  geo.DimGeographie dg  
INNER JOIN geo.ActivePerimeterDetail apd 
      ON dg.ContractId = apd.ContractId 
      AND dg.IdNiveau3=apd.PerimeterId 
      AND apd.PerimeterLevelId=3
      AND dg.ContractId = 2  
and dg.ModeGeo='PA' 
AND apd.ContractId = 2
where c.IdGeographie = dg.IdGeographie)        
GROUP BY IdFluide,
  newDate,IdUsage
```

In your index most selective column should be on left most.

Similarly in your query, write most selective predicate first.
In some cases it help.

Thing is there is huge difference between `Estimated rows` and `Actual rows` in below object

1. IX_GeographicalConsumption
2. IX_Test

This happen because either Statistics is not updated or skewed data distribution of certain index.

**New Edit** :  Good part about table `[fait].[Consommation]` is that all columns are `INT` ,`DateTime` type.

Bad part is there are so many composite keys which define the relation between tables.It is not clear which column is actually PK and how CI is populated.

There should be one column which is `identity` int (or ever increasing) Clustered Index.

It is important to know,`data distribution`,`selectivity` of each index columns of each table.Then only one can decide about What index is to be created and what should be the order in composite index.

Alter your `Composite Nonclustered Index` to `Filtered Index` on `IdUsage > 0`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_GeographicalConsumption
ON [fait].[Consommation] (IdSource,IdTypeFluide,IdUsage,IdGeographie,IdFluide,newDate) include(Conso-KW)
where IdUsage>0
GO
```

I am not sure about Order of column in index list because I am not aware about their `Selectivity`.

Notice : Column which participate in `Predicate` are in index list, they are not in `Include` list.

Like index `[IX_Test] ON [geo].[DimGeographie]` is wrong.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Test] ON [geo].[DimGeographie]
     (
         [ContractId] ASC,
         [ModeGeo] ASC,
         [IdGeographie],
         [IdNiveau3]
     )
```

Again Ordering you decide or explain.

Conclusion in same order :

1 ) Determine if number of rows return by each Table is correct or not.If not then correct Query/ where condition .It is not about Index.

2) Right  Index Plan

3) Updated Statistics

4) Memory Grant for query is based on Estimated number of Rows.Your estimated rows is less so less memory is granted.This is not enough memory to work on Actual number of Rows which is quite huge. So it spill into TempDB.

In your case there is single level spill.This spill level can increase as `Actual rows` increase and `grant memory` decrease.

So Point 1) and 2) are more important.

Lastly,

It is clear from latest Execution Plan that cost has only increase after `WITH(FORCESCAN, INDEX(0))` .So Index hint is not require.